# Filtering on where condition based on values that end in a value?

Tags: sas

Familiar with using the like function for filtering character values, is it possible to do the same for numerical values?

```
Col A     Col B
1         3214.22 
2         4432.11
3         11.65
4         342.98
```

For instance, below works for character values:

```
data test;
set table (Where = (Col B like '%.22));
run;
```

Comment: you can use `cat()` function to convert `Col B` to its char type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a computation to determine the fractional part needed for comparison.

```
data want;
  set have;
  where round ( abs(b) - int(abs(b)), 1e-8 ) = 0.22;  /* 1e-6 is rounding level, used here as a fuzz factor */
run;
```

or, per @whymath, compare the character representation of the numeric value returned by a function such as `CATS` or `PUTN`.

```
where cats(b) like '%.22'; /* character value being compared depends on BESTw. chosen by CATS */
where put(b,best15.2) like '%.22';  /* match fractional parts >= .215 to < .225 */
```

Comment: @ Richard Is there a function to re-format the character column b to a numerical column?

Comment: If you want to change character to numeric then you need convert the values not change their format.  In SAS a FORMAT is just instructions for how to display the values, does not change the values stored. The INPUT() function is how you convert a string of characters to a number. With that function you use an INFORMAT instead of a FORMAT. The normal numeric informat `32.` can by used to convert strings into numbers.